# UDP Port access

Tags: c, udp

I have a small server program in C which prints a message to the client. This program uses UDP Port for communication.

My question is: Is there a way or application by which I can test the functionality of my program from my windows machine. Example, if I type in some command, I can see the response from my program on my computer.

telnet xx.xx.xx.xx. PortNum, I believe telnet wpuld not work.

Comment: Why do you believe that `telnet` wouldn't work. And I assume you do have some sort of software to receive the message on the client, so why not just run that on your windows machine?

Comment: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-client.c

Comment: @MatsPetersson Just how much do you know about the telnet protocol?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Doh, it's not working because it's UDP - sorry, getting a bit late in the evening here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any existing tools. I assume your server receives a message from the client and sends a response message back. If this is correct, create a basic client program which sends a message (sendto()) and then calls recvfrom() (default is blocking mode on my platform), then print the response message received. This works well for me. Don't have time to ferret around for an example (which is on linux) but you should be able to use an example udp client for windows from the web, I imagine. Let me know if you would like my client program as a template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use netcat; if it's installed on your machine, it's typically executed by "nc"

netcat can connect to or listen on tcp or udp ports; -u is udp.

nc -u host port  # connect to a udp port

nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 1026 # listen on port 1026, in udp mode.

etc.